# Issue with changing borderColor in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm very new to JQuery, in fact this is the first script I've ever written. The following simply finds all DIVs with class "TestDIV", and then performs a few operations upon inputs found within them.

Everything works apart from the borderColor, which remains the colour I originally set it. Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is? I'd also be very welcome to tips on how to improve my code.

```
function hideAndShowJQ(show) {
        var hideColor = "#DFDFDF";
        //Find DIVs and modify styling
        var div = $('div.TestDIV'); //Find relevant divs
        div.css('color', (show) ? "" : hideColor) //Change text colour
            .find(':input').attr("disabled", !show) //Disable any inputs
            .attr("borderColor", "red") //Change border colour of inputs
            .attr("value", ""); //Clear any existing input text
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `borderColor` is not an attribute of the element, it's a CSS property.

To change css properties/values use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). Also, when using quotes it's `"border-color"` not `borderColor` (though as @Felix Kling notes, in the comments below, it doesn't matter about the camelCase being in quotes):

```
div.css('color', (show) ? "" : hideColor) //Change text colour
            .find(':input').attr("disabled", !show) //Disable any inputs
            .css("border-color", "red") //Change border colour of inputs
            .attr("value", ""); //Clear any existing input text
```

Given that you're using jQuery, and have an `input` element that you want to clear, it might be easier to use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val), rather than [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
.val(''); // sets the value of the input to an empty string.
```

Comment: It does not matter whether it is `borderColor` or `border-color`. Both will work. Only if you pass an object to `css`, it has to be `borderColor` if you use non-string keys.

Comment: @Felix Kling: really? I'd always assumed that it would work similarly to variables (in that they wouldn't be 'interpolated' in strings); I have no idea why I thought that, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This may work too:

```
    $('#div-name :input').attr("disabled", !show);
```

because I used the same form for border style of textbox

```
    $('#div-name :input').attr("style", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `$(this).css("borderColor","red")`.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the borderColor variable wrong.

```
$(this).css("borderColor","red");
```

Comment: This will set the text color ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand notation bellow in chrome and safari, but Mozilla don't support it.

```
$(this).css("borderColor");
```

So you have to use more specific notation for browsers compatibility. You can use this one instead:

```
$(this).css("border-top-color");
$(this).css("border-right-color");
```

etc...